# Will googlebot crawl an empty A node?

Tags: seo, googlebot

Given a page like this served from a.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://b.com/test"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Will the link be crawled despite the fact that the `<a>` node has no content?

Answer (score 0):

Will it be crawled? Probably, given the example above.

Will it be indexed and/or ranked? It depends if there's content that's worth ranking.  Will you be able to send ranking signals about b.com? No.

Comment: Interesting, why would it be thrown out?

Comment: Added a little more clarification to the answer.